# skip method always returns 0 of Inputstream

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

I have to generate checksum by reading the file and for that, first , I have to read the 8 bytes header and then skip some of bytes(that would be variable length and it is available for each file). But after reading first 8 bytes and storing to the byte array, if I run skip on the same inputstream, it always returns 0. I am not able to find out what could be the reason for that. Please find below the part of code:

```
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
DigestInputStream din = new DigestInputStream(inputstream, md);
while(din.read(headerArr,0,8) != -1){
}
byte[]headerData = md.digest();
//skip some bytes
long skippedBytes = inputstream.skip(bytesTobeskipped);
```

But, If I don't read the header then skip works fine, it tries to skip the provided bytes.
So, please help me out to resolve this issue or point me out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But after reading first 8 bytes

```
while(din.read(headerArr,0,8) != -1){
    }
```

You're not reading the first 8 bytes. You're reading the last 8 bytes, or rather the last bytes after reading some unknown number of prior bytes.

Change the `while` to an `if`, and don't ignore the count returned by the `read()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. Yeah, now it works :). I have one more doubt , once i read first 8 bytes from input stream, does pointer be on the next byte or will it be there on starting pos, because now i have to skip remianing bytes , so if do skip on remiang bytes to be skipped ,suppose next 50 bytes, then do i ve to skip on 58 bytes or 50 byes?

Comment: When you read, the pointer advances. If you read 8 and skip 50, the next byte is #58.